# А нужны ли здесь запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Это очень важно(,) всегда быть начеку.

Он это сказал(,) не потому, что слаб духом, а такие были обстоятельства.

Нужны ли зпт в скобках?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Это очень важно ― всегда быть начеку. Присоединительный инфинитивный оборот со значением пояснения для местоимения ***это***.

2) Он это сказал **не потому,** что слаб духом, **а потому,** что обстоятельства были такие (таковы).

Он это сказал **не потому,** что слаб духом,  (а) просто обстоятельства были такие.

Противопоставление: не потому, а потому.

**Примечание** (оформление предложений с противопоставлением) http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=134#pp134

Мелодии, смешиваясь со слезами, текут прямо по вашему нерву к сердцу, и вы плачете **не оттого, что** вам печально, **а оттого, что** путь к вам вовнутрь угадан так верно и проницательно (Б. Паст.).

Comment: Не ошибка, а  просто не успела вчера всё проверить и исправить.  Я в курсе условий расчленения составных союзов, например: Пастухов сошелся с Цветухиным не потому, что тяготел к актерам